# Как сделать игру Королевский квадрат (балда) в excel

Tags: excel

Как сделать игру Королевский квадрат (балда) в Excel, не используя программирования?

Только встроенные функции Excel и словарь, или как-нибудь по-другому.

[Вот тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B4%D0%B0_(%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0)) описание игры и правила. Задали сделать, сижу голову ломаю, даже мыслей нет.

Comment: Сформулируйте правила игры.

Comment: И откуда такие ограничения на использование программирования?

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov правила [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B4%D0%B0_(%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0))

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: **1.** Балда отличается от Королевского квадрата, это не одно и тоже. **2.** Покажите ваши наработки. **3.** вам как минимум нужен словарь для проверки слов.